# SQR and Oracle support

Tags: sqr

We are a somewhat heavy SQR user and powers above have told us Oracle is stopping support of SQR... I know it is heavily used but have yet to see mention of this online. I just spoke with a friend who works for ADP, a big SQR user, and she has heard no mention. Support supposedly ends as of the next Oracle database release 11?. Has anyone else heard this?

Comment: I'm with ADP and we have heard nothing.  We do use SQR heavily here and with Oracle 11.  Perhaps it will stop with Oracle 12 but I've heard nothing about this until now so your comment concerns me since you said powers above.  It could be our powers above have not shared that with us.  Couldn't find any mention online either.

Comment: I looked on Oracle's site and it says that SQR extended support ends April 2018 but that Sustaining support is indefinite  http://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/lsp-apps-chart-069285.pdf   Don't know what that means if anything.

Comment: I work for a college within the SUNY system and getting off of SQR has been a big thing over the past year... An absolute ton of work. No biggie for database updates etc... but finding an alternative for formatted reports was tough. Given the total lack of mention anywhere online I've been a bit skeptical. This could make for big problems for some if SQR stop playing nicely with future database releases. By "powers" I meant a directive from a software group associated with SUNY.